# How to merge two microphone inputs into a single virtual microphone in realtime?

Tags: audio, microphone

If I connect two microphones to my computer, how would I merge it in to a single virtual microphone. I want the person I am calling on Skype to hear both microphone inputs, preferably only using software.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure if it would be easier to do this with ALSA or PulseAudio.  But I'd recommend trying it with PulseAudio first.  What you will probably need to do is connect both of the microphone source-outputs to the same sink.  This can be done with `pactl` or `pacmd`, and perhaps with some GUI utilities like `pavucontrol`.

Comment: Could you explain how I would do that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time to do the research for you.  If I already knew the details by heart, I would have said so.  ;)  You should be able to figure out how with a combination of Google, StackExchange, and the man pages.  Try `apropos pulse` for a list of related man pages.  And really, with a bit of googling, you should be able to find out how to combine mics with PulseAudio.  For example, I found [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/alsa-and-pulseaudio-recording-multiple-input-devices-877614/) on the first page of results.

Answer (score 1):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/868817/collecting-and-mixing-sound-input-from-different-microphones, building on http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php/topic,119695.msg905379.html#msg905379 offers you an answer. It describes how to add fake channels - first one for collecting the inputs

```
  pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=inputs
```

and setting channels up for the diverse input

```
 pactl load-module module-loopback sink=inputs
```

enter the latter command once for each input; the command returns a number; the latter you need later.

the two links describe how to use pavucontrol to link these channels.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into alsa with the multi plugin.  I've only tried it for playback, but if it doesn't handle capture, perhaps you'll find an analogue for capture.